# Studying to become a teacher?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, translation

In the German language we have a word if you are studying to become a teacher (called 'Lehramt'). I was wondering whether there is a term for that discipline in the English language as well because I'm always feeling the need for a more specific word. Since English is not my first language I might just have missed a simple term for that.

Comment: I know of no such word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the terms [*pedagogy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedagogy), [*pedagogical studies*](https://www.uef.fi/en/web/skope/aineenopettajan-pedagogiset-opinnot) and [*teacher education*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teacher_education)? I think those are exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I think, looking for the German equivalent, *teacher education* would be the best fit. Would you say *I'm studying teacher education*? *Pedagogy* is (at least here) a separate field not focused on any specific discipline but rather on the general science of teaching as well as working with children and young people.

Comment: I'd say that sounds fine. Or you could say "I'm studying to become a teacher" or even "I'll be a classroom instructor when I'm done with my teacher eduction studies" or something like that.

Comment: Also, consider the term "instructor training". This one might suit you even better.